# Dark Pact condition

Tags: eldritch-horror

Say I have a dark pact condition (however that was acquired) and have an encounter that gives me a choice of taking another dark pact.  The rules say that you cannot have more than one condition of the same type.  Does it mean my the patron from the first dark pact helps again -- thus you can chose the "accept" branch.  Does it mean that you cannot chose the "accept" branch?  Does it mean that you flip the dark pact card and resolve it if you chose the "accept" branch?

...  This is linked to the [debt condition question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13782/5318).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official ruling is that you can gain the benefit only once so any subsequent instances will automatically fail. Reference form [Twitch_City](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/5030/twitch-city)'s [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/13793/5318).

Comment: Correct, you can only have one dark pact so you cannot accept the "accept" branch again until you get rid of it (and damn, those are hard to get rid of and survive).

Comment: This is also a good reason to make sure the lead investigator does not have a dark pact, since there seems to be a lot of mythos cards that causes the lead investigator to draw one.